# Understanding Components

Tags: components, aframe

Learning Aframe / Javascript at the same time.

Attempting to write my own component that changes the radius of an object to 2 on click but if if the radius of the object is already 2 then it should decrease the radius to 1.

How would I reference the sphere object that I am trying to alter the radius of in the component.

Thanks

Here is my component logic.

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('change-radius', {

schema: {
    radius: {type: 'int'}
},

init: function(){
    var data = this.data;
    this.el.addEventListener('click',

    function(){     
        if (data.radius === 1) {
            this.setAttribute('radius', data.radius);
            console.log('THIS ONE');
        } else {
            this.setAttribute('radius', 1);
            console.log('NO !!!! THIS ONE');
        }
    })
}
});
```

Here is my sphere code.

```
<a-sphere id="sphere" change-radius="radius: 2" change-color="color: #0000FF" color="#F44336" radius="1" position="0 2 -4"></a-sphere>
```

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the sphere object from the component is a matter of [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope). 
- For the attached component, `this.el` is the sphere element. 
- Inside the `this.el.addEventListener();`, `this` refers to the sphere element, as the listeners function scope is `this.el`. If it was defined elsewhere, You could [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) it ( in order to keep the `this` scope), or call it from the listener
- Otherwise You would need to make a `let el = this.el` reference, in order to access the element at Your convinience

Of course You can get any object using `document.querySelector('cssSelector)`

---

I would suggest making a boolean switch checking if the sphere is enlarged or not, then set the radius and the boolean accordingly:

```
init: function(){
  var data = this.data;
  let el = this.el;
  let enlarged = false;
  this.el.addEventListener('click',function(){  
    //BOOL SWITCH
    if(!enlarged){
      data.radius = 2;
    } else {
      data.radius = 1;
    }
    // STATE CHANGE, AND RADIUS CHANGE
    enlarged != enlarged;
    el.setAttribute('radius',data.radius);
    }
  })
}
```

Imo it's better than actual radius checking, for It's way faster to get a boolean state, than checking the object's properties.

You could just check if `data.radius == 1`, and then change the radius accordingly, may be shorter, but It's up to You